# facebook review upcomming changes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Received this alert :

> Your app "App Name here" is requesting one or more Login Permissions which have not yet been reviewed and approved for use by Facebook. You must submit for review now if you want to keep using these permissions after April 30, 2015.
>   At f8 in 2014, we announced that apps requesting more than the three basic Login Permissions (public_profile, email and user_friends) will need to be reviewed by Facebook. For this app, this change comes into effect on April 30, 2015.
>   Unless you submit for review now, after April 30, 2015, these permissions will not be shown to people logging into your app, and will be removed from your existing users.
>   By submitting for review now, you will have more time to implement any changes our review team requires. Even if your submission is rejected, the outcome of the review doesn't take effect until April 30, 2015.

This and my other apps concerning these changes does not require more permissions from the list and they are listed green:
[image]
How to proceed , what exactly me and other confused dev's should submit/be aware of

Comment: If you are not asking for any other permissions than those basic three that are approved by default, then you don’t need to do anything. (In the Facebook Developers Group on facebook.com there have been several questions about this recently, and FB employees have said that their system is sending out “false” alerts like this in same cases. They are working on it, and trying to be more specific in targeting the apps that receive these alerts.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I spent all day trying to figure out what their alert was referring to.  The Facebook login prompt in our app only references public_profile when it opens.  And all of our interactions are handled by sending a Bundle of data via a Request and RequestAsyncTask in Android.  As far as I can tell, this is NOT what they are talking about in the alert.